# flutter command "HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient()" returns error "Unsupported operation: Platform._version"

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

In flutter by executing command `HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient()` returns this error :

> Unsupported operation: Platform._version

There is solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What package are you using to create the httpClient? Try replacing it with `http: ^1.2.0`, it works great.
The second method, you can go from the console to the link to the problematic code and comment it out, this will also help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a httpClient just:

```
// import the lib with alias "http"
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// declare and use the http client
var client = http.Client();
client.post(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're presumably trying to use the [`HttpClient`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) class from `dart:io`.  `dart:io` can be used only for the Dart VM, not for the web.  If you want something that can be used for both, then use [`package:http`](https://pub.dev/packages/http).  Note that `package:http` is *not* a drop-in replacement for `dart:io'`s `HttpClient`, although a lot of people consider `package:http` to be easier to use.

If you require API-compatibility with `dart:io`'s `HttpClient`, try [`package:universal_io`](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io).